# Why is the difference between maximum and minimum of Integer arithmetically incorrect?

Tags: java, integer, subtraction

Why are the following combinations of addition or subtraction of Integer’s maximum and minimum arithmetically incorrect?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Integer.MIN_VALUE+" - "+Integer.MAX_VALUE+" = "+(long)(Integer.MIN_VALUE-Integer.MAX_VALUE));
                System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE+" - "+Integer.MIN_VALUE+" = "+(long)(Integer.MAX_VALUE-Integer.MIN_VALUE));
//the only correct result                     System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE+" + "+Integer.MIN_VALUE+" = "+(long)(Integer.MAX_VALUE+Integer.MIN_VALUE));
    }
 }
```

Output

```
-2147483648 - 2147483647 = 1
2147483647 - -2147483648 = -1
2147483647 + -2147483648 = -1
```

Comment: Casting to long doesn't prevent the integer overflow here. you are still adding and subtracting two integers that result in overflow.

Comment: Thank you, but why doesn’t (long) type casting  resolve the overflow? Should I cast maximum and minimum to long before subtraction to correct overflowing?

Comment: Yes System.out.println(Integer.MIN_VALUE+" - "+Integer.MAX_VALUE+" = "+(((long)Integer.MIN_VALUE)-Integer.MAX_VALUE)); try this . There is explicit type coersion.

Comment: Thank you, it works

Comment: @Ada glad, thank me by accepting the ansewet if that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Casting to long doesn't prevent the integer overflow here. You are still adding and subtracting two integers that result in an overflow. So cast either one of the operands in the operation to long  rather than casting the result to long.

```
Long result = Integer.MIN_VALUE+" - "+Integer.MAX_VALUE+" = "+(((long)Integer.MIN_VALUE)- Integer.MAX_VALUE)); // There is explicit type coersion.
```